# How to validate email message-id in google workspace (Gmail)

Tags: smtp, gmail, gmail-api, mime-message

I noticed that sometimes when I send a mail to a Gmail account. Gmail reject the message-id and regenerate the id.

You can identify this be by looking at the original message and seeing  "SMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN" string with in it.

For example:

```
<60f17262.1c69fb81.3e091.249dSMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com>
```

Then my original message-id added in the header ***"X-Google-Original-Message-ID"***

As it makes it harder for me to track those messages at a later stage.
I want to make sure in advance that all my message-id are valid.
I guess that Google is validating the message-id against one of the RFC standards (probably https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4). Standards tend to be very wide and sometimes vague. Can someone provide more specific rules on how Google workspace validate message-ids.

Here is am example for message id that will be considered valid by the standard but rejected by Gmail

```
  <CAFDdQNjt907n4M"kpM2zaXHA82ZCSppZOc+bYoeKuWkatrSbmw@mail.gmail.com>

  =?UTF-8?Q?<762"51b6a8a859d4c2bd7ecd70a3aff811991d6b7@localhost.eu>?=
```

I guess gmail don't like the "

See also:
[regex to validate a message-ID as per RFC2822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968500/regex-to-validate-a-message-id-as-per-rfc2822)

[gmail is modifying header(Message-ID) of incoming mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804429/gmail-is-modifying-headermessage-id-of-incoming-mails)

**Update**
Following the answer from Rafa below.
In rfc2822 you can find the following definition.

```
msg-id          =       [CFWS] "<" id-left "@" id-right ">" [CFWS]
id-left         =       dot-atom-text / no-fold-quote / obs-id-left
id-right        =       dot-atom-text / no-fold-literal / obs-id-right
no-fold-quote   =       DQUOTE *(qtext / quoted-pair) DQUOTE
```

Looking at DQUOTE for example if I follow the syntax correctly

```
DQUOTE - DQUOTE( ) finds the first double quote mark in the string and returns all characters from that point, until a second double quote mark is found. If the string does not contain at least two double quote marks, a null string is returned.
```

So the following should be a valid message id in RFC-2822
`<test.a"rfc2822"c.123@message.com>`
But it's rejected

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you posted a sample message-id that Google didn't like? There's a low chance of anyone being able to answer this question unless they work at Google and are on the team that implemented this the way it stands right now.

Comment: I was actually hoping to get some official answer hopefully from  someone at google and not something specific for few examples

Comment: Can you provide your code which creates the message and sends it?

Comment: It basically creates a random 20 char left part of ascii chars then @ and then  right part of ascii 16 chars looking at specific examples its easy to figure out the reason e.g. @@ .. etc. but I am looking for something more generic

Comment: Why do you need an answer specifically from Google if you can look and see obvious flaws in the message-ids that your code is generating (like @@ as you mentioned?)

Comment: The same tool is running against o365 and it looks like o365 is less strict. I guess diffrent system has diffrent interoperation and I need to understand gmail in this case.

Comment: Added an example that is valid by the standard and invalid in gmail

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code that replicates this?

Comment: I can't share the code due to company regulation but I added one more example.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Gmail uses RFC 2822 rather than RFC 5322 for the message-id in a message header. Make sure to use this specification when generating message-ids.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on [creating messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending?hl=en#creating_messages):

> The Gmail API requires MIME email messages compliant with [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822) and encoded as base64url strings.

Comment: Thank you for. your answer although I don't think it answer my question. This is a more general comment on the message format not message-id. RFC-2822 includes message id section but again this may have some diffrent interpretation by diffrent MTA vendors

Comment: Can you please explain what more you are looking for? Your question says `Can someone provide more specific rules on how Google workspace validate message-ids.` - to which I would say the specific rules are "Follow RFC 2822 and not RFC 5322".

Comment: I updated the question I hope this will help